# Unable to register the servlet

Tags: java, sling, aem-6

I have created a servlet. I have added the servlet path in Apache sling servlet resolver. I am firing an ajax call with the url same as the path of servlet. But the servlet is not registered, the flow does not go to the servlet after the ajax call. I am using AEM 6.5.

PFB Servlet code

```
package com.aem.poc.core.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.rmi.ServerException;

import com.aem.poc.core.service.WaterHeightService;

import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletRequest;

import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.sling.api.resource.Resource;

import org.apache.sling.api.resource.ValueMap;

import org.apache.sling.jcr.api.SlingRepository;


import java.util.*;

//DS Annotations

import org.apache.sling.servlets.annotations.SlingServletPaths;

import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;

import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Reference;

import javax.servlet.Servlet;

import org.osgi.framework.Constants;

import org.apache.sling.api.servlets.HttpConstants;

import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import org.slf4j.Logger;

@SlingServletPaths("/bin/heightSearchServlet")

@Component(service=Servlet.class)


public class WaterHeightServlet extends org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingAllMethodsServlet {

    //private static final long serialVersionUID = 2598426539166789515L;
    @Reference
    private SlingRepository repository;

    @Reference
    private WaterHeightService whs;
    List<Map> waterHeightList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void bindRepository(SlingRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServerException, IOException {
        try
        {
            String requiredHeight = request.getParameter("id");
            waterHeightList.addAll(whs.getHeightList());
            Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WaterHeightServlet.class);
            //log.debug("passed param value is"+requiredHeight);
            for (Map item: waterHeightList) {
                log.debug("map item is"+item.get("datevalue"));
            }
            //response . write() trturn the data
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The ajax call is as below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //$('body').hide().fadeIn(5000);

   $('#fetch-heightdetails').click(function() {

    var targetHeight= $('#heightValue').val() ; 

    $.ajax({

            type: 'GET',    
            url:'/bin/heightSearchServlet',
            data:'id='+targetHeight ,
            success: function(msg){   
                var json = jQuery.parseJSON(msg); 
                console.log(json);               
            }
        });
    });
  });
```

Please help resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning any response from the servlet. Use `response.getWriter().write("Hello JSON");` Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. I will surely do that. 

But the Servlet gets ignored even though i have included the path in Apache Sling servlet resolver and appropriate annotations are used. Could you please let me know when i register a servlet by path, what could be the solutions when it gets ignored.
Because when i try in system/console/servletresolver I get 'servlet does not exist' response

Comment: Can you check if '/bin/' is added in the script resolver execution paths in osgi configuration. If that is not added then you will get a 404 error when hitting the servlet path as you have registered the path starting with /bin/. It should be present by default.